# Networking - RDT 2.0 - How can this FSM transition occur?

Tags: computer-networks

I attempted this question and I do not understand why the last option is necessary in order to get the right answer.

My logic/thought-process:

In this question, only two scenarios can occur:

**Scenario 1:** Data was sent from the receiver but was corrupted. The Data is sent again and it is not corrupt this time.

For Scenario 1, the corresponding sequences of transition would be: S1,R1,S2,R2,S3

**Scenario 2:** Data was sent from the receiver and the data was intact. An ACK is received and all is well.

For Scenario 2, the corresponding sequences of transition would be: S1,R2,S3

I do not understand how a Scenario 3 can exist where the corresponding sequences of transition are: S1,R1,S2.

That is incomplete as the sender does not receive an ACK or a NAK (after they have sent the second packet)

[image: Question about sending data using RDT 2.01]